Object Library for basic geometry
For example in Houdini :

Where can I find this Library for basic geometry (box, sphere, plane, torus etc) ?
So I can just simply click them rather than using keyboard SHIFT-A -> /mesh/cube

There's a couple ways you can achieve this without using Shift+A.

Quick Favorites - You can add any operator to your Quick Favorites menu by Right Click it in the menu and selecting Add to Quick Favorites. Then, you can access your Quick Favorites by pressing Q. In your case you would do Shift+A > Left Click on mesh > Right Click on Cube > Left Click on Add to Quick Favorites.

Pie Menus - Blender has pie menus that can be activated using the Tab key in certain contexts. You can customize pie menus through add-ons like PieMenusPlus.

Custom Menus - You can find Blender addons such as MenuCreator that allow you to create custom menus in blender to make any feature easily accessible.



can I save the quick fav ? Every time I restart Blender , it's gone.

I've never used quick favs before but it looks like you just have to save your file, exit, reopen (note that QF are global for all your blend files). On Blender 4.1.0

I've never had to manually save my Quick Favorites, they should just automatically save.

If you don't like shortcuts, the same menu is available in the top bar :


I have to do 3 clicks for each object I want to create (ex : add -> mesh -> cube ) . I like the library where I can do single click to load them.

No 2 clicks. With Maj+A only 1 click and your left hand should already be on your keyboard.
